# Custom Realm not invoked in the Spring Boot Application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat

Spring boot version: 2.2.6.RELEASE

I'm migrating a legacy application to the Spring Boot.
In the legacy application, in the server.xml of the Tomcat, I had the following Realm configuration:

```
            <Valve className="com.test.realm.AuthServletValve" />

            <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />

            <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve" showReport="false" showServerInfo="false" />
        </Host>
```

I'm trying to convert this configuration in a spring configuration class with the following code:

```
@Configuration
public class TomcatConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public ConfigurableServletWebServerFactory servletContainer() {
        TomcatServletWebServerFactory factory = new TomcatServletWebServerFactory();
        factory.addContextCustomizers(TomcatConfiguration::customize);
        factory.addEngineValves(new SingleSignOn());
        factory.addEngineValves(new ErrorReportValve());
        factory.addContextValves(new AuthServletValve());
        return factory;
    }

    private static void customize(Context context) {
        context.setRealm(new AuthServletRealm());
        context.addConstraint(createSecurityConstraint());
    }


    private static SecurityConstraint createSecurityConstraint() {
        SecurityConstraint securityConstraint = new SecurityConstraint();
        SecurityCollection securityCollection = new SecurityCollection();
        securityCollection.addPattern("/*");
        securityConstraint.addCollection(securityCollection);
        return securityConstraint;
    }
}
```

Valves are invoked correctly, but my AuthServletValve is not invoked.
I expect that for every invocation of my Spring Boot API, AuthServletValve is invoked to get the principal. But nothing

Comment: did you solve it? It's my problem now